# How to add a custom template for new Entity in crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I create a new entity for sending SMS in dynamic CRM 2011.

So I want to add more thing to my solution as below:

1- create a new entity like Email Template for SMS template with exact functionality and relationship that Email and Email template have

2- put a icon in setting->Templates like Email Template

3- put a icon in my SMS form for insert template in SMS data field

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add new entity (SMS Template) but it can't have exactly the same functionalities like email template. You will have to type some code here...
   In yor SMS template you can define some placeholders for parameters, which will be filled in rendering proccess. For rendering you can use Javascript or custom workflow activity...
2. Use [xrm toolbox](http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/) for adding new button in settings menu
3. Use [ribbon editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) for adding new button on SMS form. On click call your Javascript function which will do rendering...

Hope that helps for start ;)